# My machine has running multiple application but in top utility it is showing only one process. Is it a bug in top utility?

Tags: 16.04, process, top

While using `top` utility, I noticed that it is showing total tasks: 267, 1 running, 266 sleeping. But I am running multiple applications (MP3 player, Browser, Virtualbox) at the same time in my machine.

Anyone clarify me, why it is showing only one process is running?

```
top - 18:07:36 up  2:45, 1 user, load average: 1.00, 0.65, 0.52
Tasks: 267 total,  1 running, 266 sleeping, 0 stopped, 0 zombie
%Cpu(s):  3.5 us, 1.3 sy,   0.0 ni, 94.2 id, 0.4 wa, 0.5 hi, 0.2 si, 0.0 st
KiB Mem :  8055508 total,  1616268 free, 4043328 used, 2395912 buff/cache
KiB Swap: 16777212 total, 16776852 free,     360 used, 3118724 avail Mem
```

Comment: Do you get any output when you run `systemctl status | grep vboxdrv`?

Comment: Yes, output is     │ │   │ └─23946 grep --color=auto vboxdrv

Answer (score 1):

The Unix system use the CPU in a way it `simulate` running a lot of processes in parallel.

Actually only one process can run in each CPU at any point of time.

The other processes might be in other state (e.g. sleeping)

More info can be found [here](https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/show-all-running-processes-in-linux/)

In the example in the provided link, there are 4 cpu's, and 2 running processes.